# Moving data over - need cleaner method

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a `data table` with `24 columns` (12-2 column groups). The placement of the data is all over the place and I need to compress the data into a legible Dimension table.  Here is the look of it

```
Business Key | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | Group8 | Group11 | Group12
00001        | abc123 |        | efg456 | ght456 |         |
```

I need it to look like

```
Business Key | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | Group8 | Group11 | Group12
00001        | abc123 | efg456 | ght456 |        |         |
```

I have tried `Coalescing` the data, but it repeats the columns in the latter groups once there is a blank. I have a feeling I need to temp table the data and loop it through a join, but I cannot seem to get it right.

I am pretty sure I can do it with 12 `joins`. But there has to be a more elegant solution, since I have over 80 million records to look through.

To clarify: I did the following

```
Group1 = Coalesce(group1,group2,group3,...,group11,group12)
Group2 = Coalesce(group2,group3,...,group11,group12)
Group3 = Coalesce(group3,...,group11,group12)
```

etc...
The Coalesce works for the first gap, but it keeps  moving everything over because it does not know that it already moved the data in the column before.

Comment: you mention "once there is a blank". coalesce works on nulls, so can you update blanks to nulls?

Comment: If you have two groups of these things, then I think you might have the wrong data layout.  A table with one row per key and group would make more sense for your data.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: The Coalesce is working, but too well. I do a coalesce with each column and it creates duplicates if there are spaces. So it does move everything over, but it creates false results in columns between.

Comment: @Jeremy: I have the blanks covered. I am replacing the "spaces" with a Replace function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic for `coalesce()` is a bit more complicated:

```
select coalesce(group1, group2, group3, . . . ) as group1,
       (case when group1 is not null then coalesce(group2, group3, group4, . . .)
             when group2 is not null then coalesce(group3, group4, group5, . . )
        . . .
        end) as group2,
       . . .
```

As you can see, this gets real complicated real fast.  I wonder if the following would have respectable performance:

```
select dt.businesskey, p.*
from datatable dt cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then grp end) as grp1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then grp end) as grp2,
             . . .
      from (select grp, row_number() over (order by num) as seqnum
            from (values(dt.group1, 1),
                        (dt.group2, 2),
                        . . .
                 ) v(grp, num)
            where grp is not null
           ) p
     ) p;
```

This looks quite complicated.  But SQL Server does a pretty good job of optimizing `apply` for within-row transformations.  It is worth trying to see if this works for you.